# How to calculate the size in bits of tag, index field for a CPU cache?

Tags: tags, indexing, bit-manipulation, cpu-cache

I'm writing a CPU cache emulator that will take the *size of the cache* in bytes, the *length of each cache line* in bytes, and the *number of sets/groups* in the cache.

I have most of it written, but what I've been struggling with for hours is to figure out how many bits I need to shift left/right to extract the **tag** and **index** fields of the given address.

For example, given the address **48**, I need to determine the tag and index.

Here's what I have for extracting the tag, but I'm pretty sure it's incorrect.

```
int extractTag(int address, int sets){

    int bits = exp2(sets); // number of bits to shift: 2^sets

    unsigned int tag;
    int tag = address >> (32 - bits);    

    return tag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have SETS groups of BLOCK_SIZE lines. An address can be split in tag:index:offset with log2(BLOCK_SIZE) bits for the offset, log2(SETS) for the index and the rest for the tag.

You can calculate log2 like this:

```
int ilog2 (int x)
{
    int result = 0;

    while (x != 0) {
        result++;
        x = x >> 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thus you end up with:

```
int extract_tag (int address, int sets, int block_size)
{
    int offset_bits = ilog2(block_size);
    int index_bits = ilog2(sets);

    int tag = address >> (index_bits + offset_bits);
    return tag;
}

int extract_index (int address, int sets, int block_size)
{
    int offset_bits = ilog2(block_size);
    int index_bits = ilog2(sets);

    int index = (address >> offset_bits) & ((1 << index_bits) - 1);
    return index;
}

int extract_offset (int address, int sets, int block_size)
{
    int offset_bits = ilog2(block_size);

    int offset = address & ((1 << offset_bits) - 1);
    return offset;
}
```